# Redirect in react redux-tool-kit fetchBase query interceptor

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, fetch, react-router-dom, redux-toolkit

I have a react/redux app and I'm using redux-tool-kit fetchBasequery and I'm using a custom
authInterceptor middleware where I did error handling. In authInterceptor I'm trying to redirect to Login page if I get 401 error. I'm using useNavigate for redirecting but getting error
"Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."

```
//authInterceptor.ts
import { isRejectedWithValue, Middleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import navigate from '../utils';

const authInterceptor: Middleware = () => (next) => (action) => {
  if (isRejectedWithValue(action) && action.payload.status === 401) {
    console.log('401 error');
    navigate('/login');
  }

  return next(action);
};

export default authInterceptor;
```

```
//utils.ts
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


const navigate = useNavigate();
export default navigate;
```

Is ther any better way to do this or how do I handle the redirection

Comment: Hi man, can you post the solution for the redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to use the `history` object you created together with your `Router` setup and then do a `history.push` there.

Also, you don't need a middleware for this, you probably go better about [wrapping your baseQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-re-authorization-by-extending-fetchbasequery)